# implementation of R random forest feature importance score in scikit-learn

Tags: python, r, scikit-learn, regression, random-forest

I'm trying to implement R's feature importance score method for random forest regression models in sklearn; according to R's the documentation:

> The first measure is computed from permuting OOB data: For each tree,
>   the prediction error on the out-of-bag portion of the data is recorded
>   (error rate for classification, MSE for regression). Then the same is
>   done after permuting each predictor variable. The difference between
>   the two are then averaged over all trees, and normalized by the
>   standard deviation of the differences. If the standard deviation of
>   the differences is equal to 0 for a variable, the division is not done
>   (but the average is almost always equal to 0 in that case).

Therefore, if I understand correctly, I need to be able to permute each predictor variable (feature) for OOB samples within each tree.

I understand that I can access each tree within a trained forest with something like this

```
numberTrees = 100
clf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=numberTrees)
clf.fit(X,Y)
for tree in clf.estimators_:
    do something
```

Is there anyway of getting a list of samples that are OOB for each tree?  Perhaps I can us the `random_state` of each tree to derive the list of OOB samples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although R uses OOB samples, I've found that by using all the training samples, I get similar results in scikit.  I'm doing the following:

```
# permute training data and score against its own model  
epoch = 3
seeds = range(epoch)


scores = defaultdict(list) # {feature: change in R^2}

# repeat process several times and then average and then average the score for each feature
for j in xrange(epoch):
    clf = RandomForestRegressor(n_jobs = -1, n_estimators = trees, random_state = seeds[j],
                               max_features = num_features, min_samples_leaf = leaf)

    clf = clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    acc = clf.score(X_train, y_train)    

    print 'Epoch', j
    # for each feature, permute its values and check the resulting score
    for i, col in enumerate(X_train.columns):
        if i % 200 == 0: print "- feature %s of %s permuted" %(i, X_train.shape[1])
        X_train_copy = X_train.copy()
        X_train_copy[col] = np.random.permutation(X_train[col])
        shuff_acc = clf.score(X_train_copy, y_train)
        scores[col].append((acc-shuff_acc)/acc)

# get mean across epochs
scores_mean = {k: np.mean(v) for k, v in scores.iteritems()}

# sort scores (best first)
scores_sorted = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(scores_mean, orient='index').sort(0, ascending = False)
```